# Android paw server - How to immediately endCall with telephonyService

Tags: android, ftp, xhtml

In my application i create my own paw server, there's a feature that outgoing call using select phone number from directory and call dial using click on button but i want to also call end using click on button throw wen browser

in android phone application using ITelephony.aidl you can end call its work but don't know how working in pawserver.

Answer (score 0):

The latest PAW version (0.95 beta) has a new BeanShell command that should end any call:

```
endCall();
```